# Check duplicate item workflow

Tags: 2007, sharepoint-designer

I need to make my custom list items distinct that's being used for a dropdown lookup. Please help. 
Here's the scenario. I have 2 lists, the list1 have a workflow that copies an item into my list2. This happens whenever the user creates a new record in list1. Now, the problem is that I need to set up a duplicate check somewhere to ensure that list2 items are distinct or unique. I'm thinking if there's a way in sp2007 to loop through list items to check if my new item is already exists.

Below are my two lists. When the user creates new critical maitenance activity in list1 there's a workflow that copies the criticalmaintenace activity field automatically into my list2. Now if you can see the 2nd list, you'll notice that there's a duplicate items. I need to find a way to make the 2nd list unique because I'm using it as a dropdown lookup in other list.

Maintenance Activity (List1) NewForm

**Activity :** "activity1"

ACtivities (List2) (DispForm)

**Activity**

activity1

activity1

activity2

Comment: Why don't you just make the lookup field unique? Is the workflow really necessary?

Comment: is that possible? sorry im just new to sharepoint.

Comment: the lookup field is being populated with values from list1 when the user creates a new record. I have a workflow that copies item into my second list(lookup) automatically.

Comment: Could you explain what you are doing a little better? Perhaps add some graphics? I suspect there may be a better way to achieve your desired functionality.

Comment: i've added a little representation of my lists. thanks for all the reply.

Comment: Thanks for your replies guys, I've found the solution here. http://social.msdn.microsoft.com/Forums/en-US/sharepointcustomizationlegacy/thread/9605f65b-7026-47fb-af05-c555f6de222f

Answer (score 1):

Assuming you mean that list1 CREATES an item in list2 (rather than copy)
In Sharepoint deisgner workflow.. in the Create New List Item dialog box there is an option to "Overwrite the Existing File"... this may do it for you.

[image]